# room many to many error : columns returned by the query does not have the fields

Tags: android, android-room

i have a room database with two entities and am many to many relation
but get a query error

im getting an error when using android room

**error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [nameOfWorkout,dateOfWorkout,caloriesBurntInWorkout,workoutId] in com.example.sporttracker.room.relations.WorkoutWithExercises even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [amountExercise,caloriesBurntProExercise,exerciseName,exerciseId]
public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.example.sporttracker.room.relations.WorkoutWithExercises>> fetchWorkoutWithExercises(long id);**

my entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "exercise_table")
data class Exercise(
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "amountExercise")
var amountExercise: String,

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "caloriesBurntProExercise")
var caloriesBurntProExercise: String,

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "exerciseName")
var exerciseName: String,

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "exerciseId")
var exerciseId: Long = 0L
```

---

```
@Entity(tableName = "workout_table")
data class Workout(
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "nameOfWorkout")
var nameOfWorkout: String,

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "dateOfWorkout")
var dateOfWorkout: String,

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "caloriesBurntInWorkout")
var caloriesBurntInWorkout: String,

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "workoutId")
var workoutId: Long = 0L
```

my dao:

```
@Query("""
    SELECT *
    FROM exercise_table
    WHERE exerciseId = :id
    """)
fun fetchWorkoutWithExercises(id: Long): LiveData<List<WorkoutWithExercises>>
```

my relation:

```
data class WorkoutWithExercises(
@Embedded val workout: Workout,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "workoutId",
    entityColumn = "exerciseId",
    associateBy = Junction(ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef::class)
)
val exercises: List<Exercise>
)
```

---

```
// region: entity
@Entity(

primaryKeys = ["exerciseId", "workoutId"],
foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        parentColumns = ["exerciseId"],
        childColumns = ["exerciseId"]
    ),
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Workout::class,
        parentColumns = ["workoutId"],
        childColumns = ["workoutId"]
        )
      ]
  )
  //endregion

 // region: data class
 data class ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef(
   @ColumnInfo(name = "exerciseId")
   val exerciseId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "workoutId", index = true)
    val workoutId: Long
 )
 //endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can resolve this by amending **WorkoutWithExercises** to define the relationship between **exercise_table** and the **ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef** table.

- *Foreign keys only define the constraint (rule) not a relationship (even though one implicitly exists)).*

I believe changing **WorkoutWithExercises** to be like the following code will move you along:-

```
data class WorkoutWithExercises(
    @Embedded val workout: Workout,
    @Relation(
        entity = ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef::class,
        parentColumn = "workoutId",
        entityColumn = "workoutId"
    )
    val workoutwithexercises: List<WorkoutWithExercises>,
    @Relation(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        entityColumn = "exerciseId",
        parentColumn = "workoutid",
        associateBy = (Junction(ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef::class))
    )
    val exercises: List<Exercise>
)
```

i.e. the first `@Relation` describes the relationship between the Workout and the **ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef** table
the second `@Relation` describes the relationship between the **ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef** and the **exercise_table**.

(so all three tables are related as opposed to 2)

I believe what was happing is that you were getting the rows from the **exercise_table** BUT this could not be linked (via the **ExerciseWorkoutCrossRef** table) to get the appropriate **workout_table** rows and thus columns and hence the compile message.

Comment: @OFeigenbaum It compiled OK for me. Let me check to see if I made other changes.

Comment: @OFeigenbaum For the Dao I added @Transaction and removed the LiveData (not going to do the work required for that) so had `@Transaction
    @Query("""
    SELECT *
    FROM exercise_table
    WHERE exerciseId = :id
    """)
    fun fetchWorkoutWithExercises(id: Long): List<WorkoutWithExercises>`. Otherwise the code looks the same. Oh I also added `= emptyList()` after `List<WorkoutWithExercises>`. Again it's just compiled fine.

Comment: I have updated my query:
@Transaction
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM workout_table WHERE workoutId = :workoutId")
    fun fetchWorkoutWithExercises(workoutId: Long): LiveData<WorkoutWithExercises?>

Comment: then it worked. thank you mike for the help

Comment: @OFeigenbaum that's good. If you believe the answer helped you then please tick the answer to indicate that it helped you.